# Sorting float values in a groupby in ascending order

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I am would like to sort the values in my groupby by Actual Cost in ascending order, but I keep getting the wrong result.

This is my code:

```
D16 = Dec16.groupby('PRACTICE', sort=False)["Actual Cost"].sum()
D16
```

And it returns this:

```
PRACTICE
1       19585.09
3      144741.12
5       32622.69
6      138969.68
10      33973.04
```

Does anyone know how I can sort this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe `D16` looks like this with one column `PRACTICE`

```
     PRACTICE
 0   19585.09
 1  144741.12
 2   32622.69
 3  138969.68
 4   33973.04

D16.sort_values(by='PRACTICE', ascending=True)
```

will yield;

```
    PRACTICE
 0  19585.09
 2  32622.69
 4  33973.04
 3  138969.68
 1  144741.12
```